# Authenticating Skype Bot through an API

Tags: authentication, oauth, bots, botframework

I am using Microsoft Bot Framework to build a bot that receives messages from a user and then connects to a a banking service he already registered. *(In case you don't know Bot Framework, is just a Web Api where you post messages and it answers you according to the behaviour you specified in advance).*

So the banking service knows his user and password. And let's say it also knows the user Skype's username, because the bot will be connected to a Skype Channel via Bot Framework Connector.

My question is: **how can I authenticate (in the banking service) the user that sending messages to the bot?** The idea of this is of course not to make the user send his credentials (user and password) via messages.

Making the bot send a link where the user can write  his credentials and then trigger a callback is not an option. I need to make the authorization flow the most transparent I could do it for the user.

Answer (score 0):

The only examples I currently have of Auth involve invoking a browser for the authenticating service where the user can enter their service-specific credentials, such as Mat Velloso's AuthBot sample on github: https://github.com/matvelloso/authbot

I assume your last statement means this isn't a valid option?

Comment: Exactly, I 've been told that doing this wouldn't be a valid a approach (even though is the best I have found at the moment). I saw Mat Velloso's AuthBot, he's authenticating right now with Azure AD, so in my case I should use the banking service as the Identity Provider. So I could be using the same flow he uses... But as I said, they want me to avoid that...

Comment: Any another idea? Auth0 or oAuth would fit here? I think is the same... At some point the user would be requested to send his credentials to exchange them for a token. Is any other option or that is kind of impossible?

Comment: just my idea, how about making the bot to send an OTP to user registered mobile number, and ask user to type the OTP in the chat to authenticate?

Comment: Thats exactly the solution I came to! I am researching about using Google Authenticator or Auth0 Passwordless to implement that.